# Can I use multiple MTLRenderPipelineStates in one MTLRenderCommandEncoder?

Tags: swift, metal

I'm currently making simple UI for a game, and to draw each of the buttons I need to use 2 pipeline states (same vertex shader for each). One to draw a line strip for the border, with a static color fragment shader, and one to draw the inside of the button with a rippling gradient. I'm wondering if I need two different render command encoders, one per pipeline, or if I can do the following:

```
let encoder = command.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: renderPassDesc)
encoder.setRenderPipelineState(stateWithStaticFragmentShader)
// encode some buffers and draw line-strips
encoder.setRenderPipelineState(stateWithGradientFragmentShader)
// encode some buffers and draw button background
encoder.endEncoding()
```

Comment: Do you set the same texture again for 2 pipeline states just like below?

[renderEncoder setFragmentTexture:_mtlTexture  atIndex:0];

Comment: @elmass Sorry I can't tell you. I did some stuff in Metal but that was well over a year ago and I have since flushed it out of my head.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use multiple pipeline states in one render command encoder. That's precisely why the `setRenderPipelineState()` method exists, rather than the pipeline state being part of the render pass descriptor. The properties in the render pass descriptor are only read at the time of the creation of the render command encoder and can't be changed during the lifetime of that encoder. Anything which is independently settable on the encoder can be changed during its lifetime.

Comment: Thank you that's what I figured but I wasn't sure.

Comment: Hi, 
I am doing exactly the same thing. However, I am observing only the output of 2nd fragment shader. Do you know why?

Comment: Ken, does setting the same pipeline state over and over, in order to change vertex buffers and textures, also *snapshot* the render encoder?

Comment: @trojanfoe I'm not sure what you mean by "snapshot the render encoder".

Comment: You mention in another SO answer that setting a pipeline state in the render encoder will snapshot the previous state allowing new buffers to be bound etc.  I am wondering if setting the *same* pipeline state will act the same way?

Comment: @trojanfoe Perhaps you should comment on that answer. Or open a new question. I'm still not understanding quite what you're asking. You can change any state of the encoder for which there are methods to do so. You can do that at any time. When you encode a command, that command always uses the state that was current at the time you encoded it. State changes never affect previously-encoded commands; they only affect subsequently-encoded commands.

Comment: Nevermind I think I've figured it out.  Debugging a SpriteKit run I can see that does what I am asking, so any bugs I am suffering from are elsewhere.  Sorry to bother you.