# Using multiple render pipelines in a single MTLRenderCommandEncoder: How to Synchronize MTLBuffer?

Tags: objective-c, swift, metal

**Central Issue**
I have two render pipelines in one single render command encoder. The first pipeline writes to a buffer which is used in the second pipeline. This does not seem to work and I expect it to be a synchronization problem. When I use one separate render command encoder for each render pipeline I get the desired result. Can this be solved with one single render command encoder or do I need two separate encoders to synchronize the buffer?

**Here is the more specific case:**
The first pipeline is a non-rasterizing pipeline only running a vertex shader to output to a `MTLBuffer` storing `MTLDrawPrimitivesIndirectArguments` to use for the `drawPrimitives` call for the second pipeline, which looks like this:

```
// renderCommandEncoder is MTLRenderCommandEncoder
// firstPipelineState and secondPipelineState are two different MTLRenderPipelineState
// indirectArgumentsBuffer is a MTLBuffer containing MTLDrawPrimitivesIndirectArguments
// numberOfVertices is number of vertices suited for first pipeline

// first pipeline
renderCommandEncoder.setRenderPipelineState(firstPipelineState)
renderCommandEncoder.setVertexBuffer(indirectArgumentsBuffer, offset: 0, index: 0)
renderCommandEncoder.drawPrimitives(type: .point, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: numberOfVertices)

// second pipeline
renderCommandEncoder.setRenderPipelineState(secondPipelineState)
renderCommandEncoder.setVertexBuffer(secondPipelineBuffer, offset: 0, index: 0)
renderCommandEncoder.drawPrimitives(type: .point, indirectBuffer: indirectArgumentsBuffer, indirectBufferOffset: 0)

renderCommandEncoder.endEncoding()
```

How can I make sure that the `indirectArgumentsBuffer` has been written to by the first pipeline when issuing a call to `drawPrimitives` for the second pipeline, which uses and needs the contents of `indirectArgumentsBuffer`?

Comment: Does your program function as expected if you split the work across two command buffers? If not, the problem isn’t synchronization, but a problem with the algorithm itself.

Comment: @warrenm: It does work as expected if I split the work across two different render command encoders (first renderPipeline work in first encoder, second renderPipeline in second encoder).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to use separate encoders. In this (somewhat dated) [documentation about function writes](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/MetalProgrammingGuide/WhatsNewiniOS10tvOS10andOSX1012/WhatsNewiniOS10tvOS10andOSX1012.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014221-CH14-DontLinkElementID_74), only atomic operations are synchronized for buffers shared between draw calls.